# * failed to open vchiq instance

Tags: php, shell, audio, raspberry-pi

I try to play sound from a php script to my raspberry pi 3 via the audio jack. I use in the php script the following code:

```
<?php
$fetch = 'wget "http://192.168.1.127/sound.mp3" -O sound.mp3 --no-check-certificate';
$play = 'omxplayer -o local sound.mp3';
echo shell_exec($fetch);
echo shell_exec("sudo chown upload sound.mp3");
echo shell_exec($play);
?>
```

I got the file from a local ip adress and save it to the pi. Then I play the sound via the `omxplayer` command. On the real shell (over SSH in Putty), the Pi will output the sound without any problems. When I try the script, I got the following error message when I use the omxplayer `command`.

```
* failed to open vchiq instance
```

I searched then in forums for this error. They mean that it will be something with the missing permission of the file. For that I set the whole directory to the permission level 777 and the fileowner, as you can see in the script, to `upload`.

Unfortunately, this didn't work. Does anyone have another solution to get an output from the pi?

Thanks for every responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for that problem, after I searched again. The problem was with a directory in the `/dev`. I hit the following command in the command line and it works great.

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/vchiq
```

Comment: Thank you very much it save me alot

Comment: rather than change systemwide, it's to better to change for the specific user.   sudo usermod -a -G video username.   this answer can be found over the place, like here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/how-can-i-permanently-fix-dev-vchiq-permission-errors

Comment: The "777" mode om the /dev/vchiq is hole in the security! Especially it's important to use when video camera used. Use the "video" group instead to appropriate user.

Comment: Dont do this, it allows any system user write access to the device, adjust the individual user settings as above

Answer (score 19):

Omxplayer is a video and audio player. Your user needs to be in the `video` group, even though you only want to playback audio.

Don't use the `777` mode on the `/dev/vchiq` because it's not secure! A better solution is to add your user to the system group called `video`. For example:
To add user `testuser` in your Linux system to the `video` group, use this command:

```
usermod -aG video testuser
```

Comment: This should really be usermod -aG video testuser otherwise the testuser will be removed from other groups

Comment: this solution dont work for me. Im using a Banana Pi Zero M2

Answer (score 4):

A lot of users have actually been brought to this question because they tried `raspistill` and it returned this error.

In any case, the error is usually because you forgot to add the `sudo`, so `sudo raspistill -o output.jpg` should work.